# Why is ScalaTest 3.0.1 for 2.12 not resolved?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a scala project that is cross built for 2.11 and 2.12

> crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.0")

I've added dependency for scalatest.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest"            %% "scalatest"           % "3.0.1"    % "test",
  "org.mockito"              % "mockito-all"          % "1.10.19"  % "test"
)
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Akka"       at    "http://akka.io/repository/",
  "Sonatype"   at    "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
)
```

I can see that 2.12 version is [published](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12) for scalatest from 3.0.0. SBT is not able to resolve it though.

```
[warn] ==== sbt-releases-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugins-repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://artifactory.internal.com/ivy-releases/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://artifactory.internal.com/maven-releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/scalatest_2.12-3.0.1.pom [warn] ==== Akka: tried
[warn]   http://akka.io/repository/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/scalatest_2.12-3.0.1.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/3.0.1/scalatest_2.12-3.0.1.pom [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.1 ...

[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::      UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;3.0.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any pointers to what is missing here?

**UPDATE:**
Adding my ~/.sbt/repositories setting

[repositories]

```
local  
my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://artifactory.internal.com/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
my-maven-proxy-releases: http://artifactory.internal.com/maven-releases/
```

Comment: According to your log, SBT doesn't search for the dependency on Maven Central (presumably because your global SBT configuration changes the default resolvers?). You'd need to either add Maven Central as a resolver, or make sure the Scalatest dependency can be resolved from one of your organisation's repos (artifactory.internal.com/maven-releases I'd guess).

Comment: You are right. It works when I add maven central to build.sbt.
I've set my ~/.sbt/repositories to point to artifactory. This was a recent change. I thought artifactory maven-proxy-releases will look at Maven Central by default. Something not right with our artifactory config??

Comment: Updated post with my repositories file

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first thing to do is check your artifactory config for the "maven-releases" repo. My understanding is that you need either a remote repo pointing to Maven Central or a virtual repo aggregating several repositories, including, again, a remote repo pointing to Maven Central. But I'm not an Artifactory specialist...

Comment: Yup. I'm going to talk to our artifactory admin.

Comment: Pls add this as an answer

Comment: It's done now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log, SBT doesn't search for the dependency on Maven Central, which is the most straightforward place to get Scalatest from. This is not an issue with a default SBT config (since Maven Central is one of the default resolvers); but here, you have a specific SBT config, to use your organization's internal repos instead (on `http://artifactory.internal.com`).

You need to either add Maven Central in your SBT resolvers (but that's probably not what you want, in the long term) or check with your Artifactory admins if the `artifactory.internal.com/maven-releases` repo is the one that's supposed to proxy Maven Central dependencies, and if it's properly configured. I think they should also be able to export from Artifactory a Maven configuration file pointing to the repos you need to use: you could then just copy and paste the URLs from that to your SBT config file.